# php include adds spaces to the beginning of the block

Tags: php, include

I have simple page, like:

```
...
<div><?php include 'somefile.php' ?></div>
...
```

'somefile.php'-file contains `<p>Lorium ipsum...</p>`

The browser adds spaces to the beginning of the block? look image:
http://s44.radikal.ru/i104/1209/95/87e6c2438700.jpg

And this test page http://new.arsltd.ru/test.php

Comment: can you paste what you have in your include file ?

Comment: You've cut off the style tab of Firebug...I'm sure your answer is in there.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with your test page.  I bet you have whitespace in the real `somefile.php` that you thought was insignificant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `somefile.php` has spaces or other unprintable characters (such as a BOM) before the PHP start tag.

**Update:** Indeed, your file begins with an UTF-8 BOM (the bytes `EF BB BF`). Use your text editor to save it without a BOM; you will see the file size go down by 3 bytes as confirmation.

Comment: This did not work for me (note date) - I forced ANSI with Unix EOL.
What did work was dropping the final ?> from the included file.

Answer (score 3):

There is most likely a padding or margin style directive on one of your elements. Browsers disregard whitespace when parsing HTML (as they should).

The space you see in the HTML source may be caused by a newline at the beginning of the included .php file for example (note: this still doesn't affect the way the code is rendered).

Comment: They do not disregard whitespace; they collapse it.

Comment: And then do what with it? <div> <p>something</p> </div> parses to a different DOM structure than <div><p>something</p></div>?

Comment: [Yes](http://jsfiddle.net/5r9a2/).

Answer (score 1):

`somefile.php` contains a text wrapped in `<p>` paragraph, and most certain that paragraph has a margin or a padding.

the problem in in your `test.php` it starts with an invisible unicode character.

```
<div><p> // between <div> and <p> there is an unicode character
```

Comment: this file http://new.arsltd.ru/somefile.php

Comment: not that file, `test.php`, recreate `test.php` from 0

Comment: I'm replaced <p> to <span> and Nothing has changed

Comment: Recreate the file `test.php` with: `<div><?php include 'somefile.php' ?></div>`

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of 'somefile.php' ? Try changing the encoding of that file in UTF-8 without BOM with Notepad++ or other IDE/Text Editor

Comment: this file http://new.arsltd.ru/somefile.php alredy UTF-8

Comment: Yep but UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM are different. For more explanations : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark